# What is the name of a land lot with building built on that?

Tags: word-request

A vacant (land) lot is a lot without any building built on it. What is a name of a lot with a building (of any kind) built on that?

Can I name it an occupied lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [an occupied **lot**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22second%20name%20is%20jones%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22an%20occupied%20lot%22&oq=%22an%20occupied%20lot%22&gs_l=serp.3...854586.854586.0.855163.1.1.0.0.0.0.62.62.1.1.0....0...1c.1.22.psy-ab..1.0.0.lr3UNcBPes0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=4a541bedf55cb907&biw=1484&bih=929) sounds really weird, because *lots* are invariably *vacant* (there are only 273 instances of OP's version in the Google Books link there, compared to 1,820,000 for [a **vacant** lot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22improved%20land%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20vacant%20lot%22&oq=%22a%20vacant%20lot%22&gs_l=serp.3...406616.411274.0.411834.25.21.0.0.0.3.142.1328.19j2.21.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..25.0.0.FQYIi5nRRg4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.jOYpRJj4zMA.O&fp=c0b43071fc779672&biw=1369&bih=911)).

And per Tom Au's comment to Jim's answer, *improved* is more evocative of the Monopoly board game. It's also worth noting that [the vast majority of written references](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22improved%20land%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to *improved land* seem to be in relation to *agricultural land*, where the term is defined [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EWO7jbFh8oEC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=define%20%22improved%20land%22%20farms&source=bl&ots=sQGgMLEV3s&sig=c5Zt2UJRcS2bPToHZmMaG9gYeDQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=upf4UfCoMpG20QXsy4GgAg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=define%20%22improved%20land%22%20farms&f=false) as...

> ***Improved land*** includes all land regularly tilled or mowed, land in pasture which has been cleared or tilled, land lying fallow, land in gardens, orchards, vineyards, and nurseries, and land occupied by farm buildings.

I'd advise OP to call his one a [**developed site**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22second%20name%20is%20jones%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a%20developed%20site%22&oq=%22a%20developed%20site%22&gs_l=serp.3...19970.19970.1.20533.1.1.0.0.0.0.56.56.1.1.0....0...1c.1.22.psy-ab..2.0.0.Lm9hDF_teg4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=4a541bedf55cb907&biw=1484&bih=929) (12,900 written instances there).

---

EDIT: It's worth noting that not only has *an improved lot [never had any real currency **in the UK**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20improved%20lot,a%20developed%20site&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)*...

[image]

...but it's also being replaced by *a developed site [over recent decades **in the US**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20improved%20lot,a%20developed%20site&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=)*...

[image]

Comment: And yet there are organizations such as [LICA](http://www.licanational.com/) Land Improvement
Contractors of America, and it's what the [IRS uses](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p946/ch02.html#en_US_2012_publink1000107405): Land improvements include swimming pools, paved parking areas, wharves, docks, bridges, and fences.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not arguing against usages such as *land improvement* (or the exceptionally common ***home** improvement*). I'm just saying that (in the UK, at least) we wouldn't normally refer to anything as an *improved lot*.

Answer (score 5):

The term is [*improved*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_improvement).

> Home building and containment [are] two of the most common improvements.
>
> Home building pertains to anything from a house made of all stone, or a shack made of sticks. Containment consists of items such as walls, fences, roads, paths and gates.

Comment: "Improved" is the term used in Monopoly.